# Updating the left side of a string up to a delimiter

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

My column "`ColumnOne`" in my table "`MyTable`" has values like this:  Delimiter is character **'-'**

```
|Something                  |   
|Something - SomeOtherThing |
|Something - SomethingElse  |   
|Something - Whatever       |
|OtherThing -               |
```

I want to update the values so eventually it look like this:

```
|Something                  |   
|           SomeOtherThing  |
|           SomethingElse   |   
|           Whatever        |
|                           |
```

So basically algorithm being to replace with white space and keep going until you see '-' , replace that too also with whitespace.

I tried the `REPLACE` command to say like
`UPDATE MyTable SET ColumnOne = REPLACE(ColumnOne, ' - ', '   ' + ColumnOne)` but that's wrong. I couldn't figure out the pattern for its second argument.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `charindex` to find the amount of characters to change, `stuff` to perform the change, and `replicate` to generate a string of N spaces. Try this:

```
stuff(ColumnOne,1,charindex('-',ColumnOne),replicate(' ',charindex('-',ColumnOne))
```

Comment: oh I did not know about REPLICATE function at all.